# How to place {} and () in symbol across multiple rows of table

Tags: tables, symbols, multirow

I'm a LaTeX newbie making a first post. I have a table as follows:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cl}
     \multirow{2}{*}{\emph{NewElement} ``item'',} & \emph{NewElement}(``title'', ``US sanctions North Korea over Sony''),\\
                                                  & \emph{NewElement} ``pubDate'',
     ``Fri, 02 Jan 2015 20:07:38 GMT'') \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which compiles into this:

[image]

But if I want to add {} and () symbols as follows, how can I do it?

[image]

If you can forgive my modest artistic attempts!

So the left round bracket occurs after the first NewElement and after the text "item", the left brace occurs. Then at the end, a right brace and right bracket occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\emph{NewElement}$\left(
  \mbox{``item'',}\left\{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \emph{NewElement}(``title'', ``US sanctions North Korea over Sony''),\\
    \emph{NewElement} ``pubDate'', ``Fri, 02 Jan 2015 20:07:38 GMT'')
    \end{tabular}
  \right\}
\right)$

\end{document}
```

[image]